# Why eclipse open the Scaladoc instead of Javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, scaladoc

I'm working with Apache Spark Java API in Eclipse, but when I click the method and classes in Eclipse, the Scaladoc version of the Apache Spark, will opened!
How can I solve this problem?